# WPF. Setting dependency properties of custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I know there have been a lot of questions answered about dependency properties but none of the ones I've read have solved my problem so here goes.

I have a simple user control with a button and a text block. The text block holds a number which I want to be able to set from the window or view containing the control. I also need to be able to increment the value by pressing the button in the control.

Here's my main window:

```
    <Window x:Class="DependencyPropertiesTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertiesTest">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <local:UserControl1 Margin="10" UserControlNumber="{Binding Number}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" Margin="10"/>
            <Button Content="n" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DependencyPropertiesTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Number = 1;
        }

        private int number;
        public int Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set
            {
                number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Number++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my custom control:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="DependencyPropertiesTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Width="100">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserControlNumber, TargetNullValue='nn',  FallbackValue='ff'}" Margin="5"/>
                    <Button Content="+" Margin="5" Width="30" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Viewbox>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DependencyPropertiesTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }



        public int UserControlNumber
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(UserControlNumberProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UserControlNumberProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UserControlNumber.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlNumberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlNumber", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(0));



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControlNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

The two buttons in the main window should each increment the value in the text block of the user control, one from the window and one from the control itself. I can set the value from the main window as a literal like this:

```
<local:UserControl1 Margin="10" UserControlNumber="5"/>
```

but when I try to give it a binding value, it doesn't work.Checking the binding with Snoop gives the following error:

Message: Cannot set Expression. It is marked as 'NonShareable' and has already been used.

UPDATE.

I've now tried this but it still isn't working:

```
        public int UserControlNumber
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(UserControlNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserControlNumberProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UserControlNumber.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlNumber", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(0, TextBlockPropertyChanged));

    private static void TextBlockPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = d as UserControl1;
        int newNumber = (int)e.NewValue;

        uc1.MyTextBlock.Text = newNumber.ToString();
    }
```

In the main window:

```
<local:UserControl1 Margin="10" UserControlNumber="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: I always set the property changed callback in the metadata and use it to set the text block in the callback.  It binds from from a client app.   Did you consider that approach?

Comment: I gave it a shot. See the update, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

in your Window Xaml you chould Bind in TwoWays mode:

```
<local:UserControl1 Margin="10" UserControlNumber="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWays}"/>
```

Otherwise internally in the User control the value will increase but the binding in the window won't let it change ... With a TwoWays binding the Number in the window will also change.